# How to move the left div container in a container when moving scroll up and down

Tags: css

```
#main-container {
    contain: content;
  }
  #left-container-float {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0%;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    max-width: 400px;
    width: 100%;
   
  }
```

[image]

here in this pic. I want to move the div container when moving the scroll up to the height of the main container. Please help me with how to solve this.

Comment: try to handle this with javascript, use `onscroll` event and in the event handler change anything you want

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
#left-container-float{
   position:sticky;
   top:0;
}
```